# how to compare several dataframes in pandas and return the difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if i have three data frames:

df1:
Test
1
2
3

df2:
Test
4
5
6

df3:
Test
4
7
8

and i want the output to print only the values that are in df3 but not in the rest of dataframes.
output should be: 7 8
how?

Comment: 'Test' is the column name

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the ways of getting there

```
#concat 1 and 2
df12 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# use isin to find the difference
df3.Test[~df3.Test.isin(df12.Test)].tolist()
```

Comment: Awesome its working! , but its also printing 'Test'. how to get rid of it?

Comment: I adjusted above to print a list of values